# Data Factory Execution Order on Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm having some troubles with the execution order of scheduled pipelines in Data Factory.

My pipeline is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Copy_Stage_Upsert",
    "properties": {
        "description": "",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:10:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "csv_extracted_file"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "stage_table"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "retry": 2
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Copy to stage table"
            },
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT * from table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id from stage_table) UNION ALL SELECT * from stage_table"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:10:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "stage_table"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "upsert_table"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "retry": 2
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Copy"
            },
            {
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "sp_rename_tables"
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "upsert_table"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "table"
                    }
                ],
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Hour",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Rename tables"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2017-02-09T18:00:00Z",
        "end": "9999-02-06T15:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "",
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

For simplicity imagine that I've one pipeline called A with three simple tasks:
*Task 1*, *Task 2* and finally *Task 3*.

**Scenario A**

*One execution of Pipeline A scheduled*.

It runs as:

Task 1 -> Task 2 -> Task 3

**Scenario B**

Two or more executions of Pipeline A scheduled to be executed.

It runs as:

First Scheduled Pipeline Task 1 -> Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 1 -> First Scheduled Pipeline Task 2 -> Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 2 -> First Scheduled Pipeline Task 2 -> First Scheduled Pipeline Task 3 -> Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 3.

Is it possible run the second scenario as:

First Scheduled Pipeline Task 1 -> First Scheduled Pipeline Task 2 -> First Scheduled Pipeline Task 3, Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 1 -> Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 2 -> Second Scheduled Pipeline Task 3

In other words, **I need to finish the first scheduled pipeline before the second pipeline starts**.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. However, it will require some fake input and output datasets to enforce the dependency behaviour and create the chain as you describe. So possible, but a dirty hack!

This isn't a great solution and it will become complicated if your outputs/downstream datasets in the second pipeline have different time slice intervals to the first. I recommend testing and understanding this.

Really ADF isn't designed to do what you want. It's **not** a tool to sequence things like steps in a SQL Agent job. ADF is for scale and parallel work streams.

As I understand in whispers from Microsoft peeps there might be more event driven scheduling coming soon in ADF. But I don't know for sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate that this is a hack but could you please post an example?  I'm guessing what it might look like, but it would be good to have the input of an informed person.  Everything I have tried so far has failed.